# Twitter Favourites Rate Limits

Tags: twitter

I have a quick question regarding the rate limits for Twitter Favourites - specifically the GET favorites/list call. I built **favourites.io** to keep track of my favourites. It lets you search and organise your favourites.

Anyway, it works as follows:

- You sign up and authorize the application
- It imports your favourites (every 15 minutes it makes a call to GET
  favourites/list and imports any new tweets that you favourited)
- It uses the user's access token to make the call

When checking the log file I noticed that one of the import jobs failed for a particular user. The error was: "Rate Limit Exceeded".

My understanding was that an authorized user could make 15 requests in a 15 minute window (and each request could return a maximum of 200 favourited tweets)

My job was running once every 15 minutes, so I'm not sure why that user is getting the "Rate Limited Exceeded" error.

Why might this be happening?

Thanks in advance,

Ross

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down on how you built your script. If you're doing the timer from your side, it might not coincide with the one Twitter has.

For example if you send 1st call at 12:00:00 PM there's some latency lag (minor) by the time it gets to Twitter let's say 12:00:02. Now twitter expects the next call no sooner than 12:15:02, but if you have the timer script running every 15 minutes from your side, it'll send the second one at 12:15:00 < 12:15:02 so twitter rejects your call.

I would say start increasing the timer by 1-3 seconds (1 to be liberal, 3 conservative) until you give some room for Twitter to get and process your request.

Comment: Hi Leb. I changed the job to run once every 30 minutes but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: It makes 1 call per user, and there are just 5 users.  My understanding is that a user can make 15 requests in a 15 minute window.

Comment: That's very weird. After you make your call try calling [GET application/rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/application/rate_limit_status) to see what it's giving you.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank Leb.

Comment: No problem, let me know.